# Probability Calculation for a Chess game

Tags: probability

[image]

Here, I did not understand how to use the information. I know for the first 12 games the probability of Peter winning=6/12 and P(John winning)=4/12 and P(Draw)=2/12. But my question is about the next 3 games. So what am I supposed to do with the first information? How am I going to use that information in my calculation to solve these problems?

I still tried and considered three outcomes: Win, Lose, Draw. So total there would be 27 sample points. So for a. I did P=1/27. Please can somebody help me?

Comment: The question is poorly phrased. I think they want you to assume that the probabilities of wins/losses/ draws remain fixed throughout.

Answer (score 1):

From previous information, assuming that results of the previous matches hold for future matches, P(Peter wins) $=\frac6{12} = \frac1 2\;$ and so on

**(a):** P(Peter wins next $3$ games) $=(\frac1 2)^3 = \frac 1 8$

**(b)** If two games ended in a draw whose known Pr $= \left(\frac 1 6\right)$,

one game was a won by *someone or other* with $Pr =\left(\frac5 6\right)$

and thus indicated  $Pr = \binom 3 2 \left(\frac 1 6\right)^2\left(\frac 5 6\right)^1$

You should be able to do the rest similarly